# POST and GET for the same URL - Controller - Spring

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-mvc

I have this Controller :

```
@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello.html")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

        String message = "Hello World, Spring 3.0!";
        return new ModelAndView("hello", "message", message);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String viewLogin(Map<String, Object> model) {
        User user = new User();
        model.put("userForm", user);
        return "LoginForm";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String doLogin(@Valid  @ModelAttribute("userForm")  User userForm,
            BindingResult result, Map<String, Object> model) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "login";
        }

        return "LoginSuccess";
    }
}
```

I have 2 methods having different http methods for the same url `/login`
so when clicking on the first url '`localhost:8080/project_name/login`' the first method with `GET` will be handled and will redirect me to the `/LoginForm`

So from my understanding the second method handler will not be executed as the request for `/login` is always with `GET.`

If my understanding is wrong please explain to me how can the second method will be exectued and thanks.

Comment: Well, you have the code, so why don't you just let it run and see how it behaves?!? And yes, you're right. Calling the url directly via browser url will call the viewLogin handler and not the doLogin method. When you have a login form with method POST and you click a submit button within this form, then your second method should be called.

Comment: @MarcusK. yeah this is the right explanation. So we are seeing other pages but the url is kept the same that's why when submitting the form another call to `/login` will be performed but with POST method. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> the request for /login is always with GET

I think this is where you are getting confused. It's GET because the browser makes a GET call by default. If you want to evoke the second method, you may have to write a custom form / JSP page or check out [postman](https://www.getpostman.com) to set the HTTP method to POST.

You can also use curl from command line:

```
$ curl -d "param1=value1&param2=value2" -X POST http://localhost:3000/data
```

If you want to be able to make POST calls from your browser itself, checkout these browser add-ons : 
[firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/restclient/), [chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo),

If you do not like extensions in your browser, create a bookmark with the following text and use it :

> javascript:var%20my_params=prompt("Enter%20your%20parameters","var1=aaaa&var2=bbbbb");%20var%20Target_LINK=prompt("Enter%20destination",%20location.href);%20function%20post(path,%20params)%20{%20%20%20var%20xForm=%20document.createElement("form");%20%20%20xForm.setAttribute("method",%20"post");%20%20%20xForm.setAttribute("action",%20path);%20xForm.setAttribute("target",%20"_blank");%20%20%20for(var%20key%20in%20params)%20{%20%20%20if(params.hasOwnProperty(key))%20{%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20hiddenField%20=%20document.createElement("input");%20%20%20%20%20%20hiddenField.setAttribute("name",%20key);%20%20%20%20%20%20hiddenField.setAttribute("value",%20params[key]);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20xForm.appendChild(hiddenField);%20%20%20%20%20}%20%20%20}%20%20%20document.body.appendChild(xForm);%20%20xForm.submit();%20}%20%20%20parsed_params={};%20my_params.split("&").forEach(function(item)%20{var%20s%20=%20item.split("="),%20k=s[0],%20v=s[1](https://www.getpostman.com);%20parsed_params[k]%20=%20v;});%20post(Target_LINK,%20parsed_params);%20void(0);

Answer (score 1):

A hit from the browser for the url `localhost:8080/project_name/login` will be a GET call; so your first /login GET method will be executed.

To have the second method executed, make a POST call from any Rest client like [PostMan](https://www.getpostman.com/) or [ARC](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo?hl=en-US) etc.

Answer (score 0):

[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCXDS.png)

The Browser default choose the GET method . so if you try in postman you can see the difference. you have option to choose GET / POST.
For realtime also from the UI they will mention specific to GET request / Post request so no worries.

you can use the postman for better way